# Appropriate data structure for fast searching "between" pairs of longs

Tags: c#

I currently (conceptually) have:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<long, long, Guid>>
```

given a `long`, I need to find the "corresponding" `GUID`.

the pairs of `long`s should never overlap, although there may be gaps between pairs, for example:

```
1, 10, 366586BD-3980-4BD6-AFEB-45C19E8FC989
11, 15, 920EA34B-246B-41B0-92AF-D03E0AAA2692
20, 30, 07F9ED50-4FC7-431F-A9E6-783B87B78D0C
```

For every input `long`, there should be exactly `0` or `1` matching `GUID`s.

so an input of `7`, should return `366586BD-3980-4BD6-AFEB-45C19E8FC989`

an input of `16` should return `null`

**Update:** I have about 90K pairs

How should I store this in-memory for fast searching?

Thanks

Comment: The other i stumbled upon the concept of finger tree. I did not have the time to check exactly what it is but it might worth the try. http://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/the-swiss-army-knife-of-data-structures-in-c/

Comment: @David why have you changed my question? That isnt what I'm asking....

Comment: @AndrewBullock, I wish to help, not bother. I saw you have reverted back, sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as they're stored in order, you can just do a binary search based on "start of range" vs candidate. Once you've found the entry with the highest "start of range" which is smaller than or equal to your target number, then either you've found an entry with the right GUID, or you've proved that you've hit a gap (because the entry with the highest smaller start of range has a lower *end* of range than your target).

You could potentially simplify the logic very slightly by making it a `Dictionary<long, Guid?>` and just record the start points, adding an entry with a null value for each gap. Then you just need to find the entry with the highest key which is less than or equal to your target number, and return the value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I am sorry, not a solution for your IEnumerable):

```
public static Guid? Search(List<Tuple<long, long, Guid>> list, long input)
{
    Tuple<long, long, Guid> item = new Tuple<long,long,Guid> { Item1 = input };
    int index = list.BinarySearch(item, Comparer.Instance);
    if (index >= 0) // Exact match found.
        return list[index].Item3;
    index = ~index;
    if (index == 0) 
        return null;
    item = list[index - 1];
    if ((input >= item.Item1) && (input <= item.Item2))
        return item.Item3;
    return null;
}

public class Comparer : IComparer<Tuple<long, long, Guid>>
{
    static public readonly Comparer Instance = new Comparer();

    private Comparer()
    {
    }

    public int  Compare(Tuple<long,long,Guid> x, Tuple<long,long,Guid> y)
    {
        return x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A B-tree is actually pretty good at this.  Specifically, a B+-tree where each branch pointer has the start of your range as the key.  The leaf data can contain the upper bound, so you deal with gaps correctly.  I'm not sure if it's the best you could find anywhere, and you'd need to engineer it yourself, but it should certainly have very good performance.